# How can I determine if a system is equilibrated?

Tags: simulation, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo

Cross-posted in [SCSE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/43930/39670) and [MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12510/3990)

I am experimenting with a new MCMC protocol and new research.

In the context of Monte Carlo simulation, a "state of equilibrium" refers to a condition where the system being simulated has reached a stable configuration or distribution of properties that does not significantly change over time. This state represents a balance or equilibrium between the various forces, interactions, and constraints acting on the system.

I wrote the following function to test if a system is equilibrated:

```
import numpy as np

def is_equilibrated(data, shave_size=50000):
    returns = False
    mid_index = len(data) // 2

    first_half = data[:mid_index]
    second_half = data[mid_index:]

    decimals = 6

    while True:
        first_auto_corr = np.correlate(first_half, first_half, mode='full')
        second_auto_corr = np.correlate(second_half, second_half, mode='full')

        corr1 = np.corrcoef(first_auto_corr, second_auto_corr)[0, 1]

        print(f"Size {len(first_half)} vs. {len(second_half)}")
        print(f"corr  = {corr1} ")

        first_half = first_half[shave_size:]
        second_half = second_half[shave_size:]

        if corr1 == 1.0:
            break

    return returns
```

The function iteratively compares the autocorrelation of two halves of the input data, shortening the dataset at each iteration, until perfect correlation (equilibrium) is achieved between the two halves or until the loop is manually terminated.

I wrote this function to check if my simulation data is "matured" enough to analyze, i.e., good enough to computationally extract further information. In other words, it lets me know if I ran the simulation long enough to obtain a useful dataset.

The drawback of this algorithm is that it uses autocorrelation computation, which takes a lot of time, irrespective of the programming language used.

Can you propose any **alternative** technique?

Comment: Could you define *equilibrated*? Could you define *better* (as in *better technique*)? What are you doing this for, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RichardHardy, check the edit.

Comment: Thank you, much better now.

Comment: Re "...until perfect correlation (equilibrium) is achieved between the two halves...":; that will never happen unless your simulation is so incredibly flawed that it cycles within a short period.  What, then, do you really mean to achieve?

Comment: @whuber, *that will never happen unless your simulation is so incredibly flawed that it cycles within a short period.* --- I know that and that is why I posted the question. *What, then, do you really mean to achieve?* --- either a minimum correlation value to make the test marginally successful or an alternative technique/algorithm.

Comment: Why don't you use standard criteria for assessing when to stop the simulation, then?  What's the point of examining correlations and comparing correlations between segments of the simulation?

Comment: @whuber, I have little or no knowledge about testing the equilibrium of a Markov chain. I saw a video yesterday: [How to tell if your simulation is equilibrated by Charlie Laughton (Nottingham)](https://youtu.be/Ga6wMm0johE) and tried to replicate the process.  However, so far, the outcome is not satisfactory. It seems like either the algorithm needs more tuning or the algoritjm needs to be changed.

Comment: @whuber, The video says I need to *choose one criteria* and be consistent with it. I chose autocorrelation and correlation as the criteria.

Comment: @whuber, I don't know what standard criteria I can use. Can you suggest something?

Comment: I have found some good practical advice and examples in the documentation for MCMC-based Bayesian analysis software like BUGS and STAN.  More formal accounts can be found in modern textbooks on Bayesian methods.